# Getting contents of WriteTo File in a subclass

Tags: java

Here I have this code shortened to show the most important methods in question: The method void writeToFile(string filename) is in my superclass called "Words"

```
public void writeToFile(String filename) throws IOException {

        FileWriter out = null;
        try {
            File outFile = new File(filename);
            out = new FileWriter(outFile);

            out.write("Writing to a text file");

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(out != null) { out.close(); }
        }
    }
```

I also have this method below in my concrete sub class which creates a file with a given name:

```
public Vowels makeVowels(String filename) throws IOException, InvalidSequenceException {

        writeToFile("vowels.txt");
        Vowels vowel = new Vowels(this.getDescription("vowels.txt"), this.getContent("vowels.txt"));

        return vowel;

    }
```

If I call the method writeToFile("vowels.txt") from my subclass to create a new file this does not create the file ? How can I call the writeToFile method from my subclass to create this vowels.txt file ?

Comment: location of where the `File` is created is not affected by whether the code is called from a a subclass or not.

Comment: Also, no idea of what `getDescription` does, but you are using a different filename being passed to this method.

Comment: getDescription() gets the firstline of my text file whilst the getContent() gets the whole content fof my file

Comment: **vowels.txt** vs **Vowels.txt**

Comment: I want writeToFile("Vowels.txt") in my public vowels makeSequence; to create a new txt file using the method in the superclass?

Comment: @Scary Wombat. yes I haved edited that one as well. Could you explain why writeToFile("vowels.txt") is not creating any file at all based on the method in my superclass?

Comment: try debugging it, to make sure that it is being entered into.

Comment: add a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`
  } in `writeToFile()` .Do you see the output on the console? your file is created in the current directory (printed by the debug println(), make sure that's where you're checking for the file

Comment: Strage enough if i put System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); in my writeToFile(), there is no output on the console. and if I print a line of text in public Vowels makeSequence(String filename) there is no output as well. just not sure what am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to move the writeToFile("vowels.txt") from my vowels method to a different place such as in my constructor or creating a new method and calling this writeToFile("vowels.txt") works. Also as suggested by Robertos Attias using System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); showed the current directory.